# How to make Google map animate in background just like Smarty Pins?

Tags: google-maps, angular, google-maps-api-3

My website is based on a map-service. I'm trying to make a login page in which I want to implement the animation in the background to maps just like done in Google's [Smarty Pin](https://smartypins.withgoogle.com/). But I'm not able to understand how should I animate it?

I have taken some reference from [here](https://www.labnol.org/internet/embed-google-maps-background/28457/).

My project is based on Angular 2.

Comment: What about calling a `map.panBy(x, y)` on map `idle` or `bounds_changed` event? You would of course need to handle what happens once you reach the map borders (North / South) but I guess that shouldn't be too much of an issue...